# Is it possible to classify two lines as acute or obtuse with this limited information?

Tags: math, rendering, polygon

I'm trying to determine if two arbitrary lines (in 3D space) form the inside or outside of a corner.

Going in, the data I have is the two vertices that form the join, the endpoints, and the normal.

[image: Illustration of the data going in]

The data I have to work with is the position of the purple dot (which is actually two discrete vertices) the orange dots, and the direction of the two face normals (the green arrows).  With just this info, can I determine if the two lines comprise an acute angle or an obtuse angle?

(I do have a brute-force solution for this, but the routine in question needs to be as fast as possible)

Comment: Two words: dot product.

Answer (score 0):

If you take `dot(bNormal, a)` you will get a signed value encoding if the normal is pointing towards or away from the other vector.

[image: insidenormals]

taking `dot(bNormal, a)`:

[image: dot(nB,A)]

You can see that the value will be *positive*.

If normals are pointing outwards:

[image: outside normals]

taking `dot(bNormal, a)`:

[image: dot(nB,A)]

You can see that the value will be *negative*.

From this, you can conclude that:

- if `(dot(bNormal, a) > 0`, the angle between the vectors will be acute
- if `(dot(bNormal, a) < 0`, the angle between the vectors will be obtuse
- if `(dot(bNormal, a) == 0`, the vectors are parallel and the angle is neither acute or obtuse

Comment: Hi there, so I tried dot product first of course!  Here's my issue-- if I take two normals, 1,0,0 and 0,1,0 this forms the acute corner in my left illustration.  Dot product is 0.  Now if I take normals -1,0,0 and 0,-1,0 that forms the obtuse corner in my second illustration-- and the dot product is also zero.  Unfortunately I'm mostly dealing with 90 degree corners in this sorting process.

Comment: Hi, what you are saying is true, but consider the top orange point as (1,0,0) and the pink point as (0,0,0) with vector arithmetic you can obtain v = o - p = (1,0,0). If you dot the normal of the other side, (1,0,0) with this it will be 1. But consider the normal was pointing in the opposite direction, the dot product will be -1. So instead of dotting both normals, dot one side with the others normal to have a way to separate acute angles from obtuse. Goodluck!